# Netbeans 7.3.1 change non printable chars to custom ones

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.3

Is there a way to replace the default non printable chars to custom ones? I want to be able to let them visible all the time in such a way that they will not disturb my reading.

I want to be able to replace:

1. . (space) to nothing
2. > (tab) to ▸
3. ¶ (eol) to ¬

I'm curious if something like that is possible.

I have achieved something like that in vim:
[image]

Comment: Short of writing a new editor for Netbeans, I know of no way to accomplish what you are looking for. It'd be a nice feature, and I'd suggest making the request over on Netbeans.org (https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html).

Comment: Such a change would be nice. If you filed such an RFE please post the issue number for reference here.

Comment: @RobertB, Ben If you can submit the request please feel free to do so, i have tried to sign up for an account and the email for registration is not reaching my e-mail, I do not know what are the technical problems that prevent me from submitting this request. If you manage to fill such a RFE please post the issue number reference here.

Comment: Here we go. I filed the issue https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242173 for you